# String parsing and saving ipaddress to file in Java

Tags: java, parsing, file, ip-address

Following function will parse string `resp`, which will be like shown in following example. I will get an IP address in the form of a hexadecimal string like "C0A2AA32" and I need to convert that string and save it to a file.

Example of `resp`: "This is just a string with ip="2342A022" now I need to parse it"

```
void WritePublicIPAddressToFile(String resp)
{
    //find string in response
    String stringToFind = "ip="; 

    //get index of stringToFind
    int indexOfIP = resp.indexOf(stringToFind);

    String newString = "";

    //find exact ip address which will be after = in stringToFind 
    for(int i = indexOfIP; i<resp.length(); i++)
    {
        while(resp.charAt(i++) != '\"');

        while(resp.charAt(i) != '\"')
        {
            newString += resp.charAt(i++); 
        }

        break;
    }

    int lenNewString = newString.length();
    String newIPAddress = "";

    //get two bytes from hex string and convert to ipaddress 
    if(lenNewString == 8) //lenth of ipaddress raw data should be 8
    {
        long l;
        for(int i = 0;i<lenNewString;i+=2)
        {
             l = Long.parseLong(String.format("%c%c", newString.charAt(i),newString.charAt(i+1)),16);
             newIPAddress += String.format("%d.", l);
        }
    }

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(newIPAddress);
    sb.deleteCharAt(sb.length() - 1);//remvoe last '.' in ipaddress



    //final ipaddress to save in file
    newIPAddress = stringToFind + "\"" + sb.toString() + "\"";

    //write IP Address to file

    File file = new File("SomeFilePath.txt");
    FileWriter fileWriter;

    try {

        fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
        fileWriter.write(newIPAddress);

        fileWriter.flush();
        fileWriter.close();

    } catch (IOException e2) {

        e2.printStackTrace();

    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters you can simplify the first part by utilizing the fact that [indexOf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4988050/java-indexof-method-for-multiple-matches-in-string) can accept a second character indicating start point. This would lead to something like the following:

```
// Find indices for IP-address
int startIndex = resp.indexOf('\"', resp.indexOf("ip=")) + 1;
int endIndex = resp.indexOf('\"', startIndex);

String ipString = resp.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
```

Secondly, you can simplify the conversion by utilizing the substring method a little, and improve a little on performance by using `StringBuilder`, like in the following:

```
StringBuilder ipAddress = new StringBuilder();
int lenIpString = ipString.length();

//get two and two bytes from hex string and append to ipaddress 
if (lenIpString == 8) {
    long ipPart;
    for(int i = 0; i < lenIpString; i += 2)
    {
         ipPart = Long.parseLong(ipString.substring(i, i + 2), 16);
         ipAddress.append(String.format("%d.", ipPart));
    }

} else {
    throw new Exception("IP-string not long enough");
}
```

Note that this also does something if in the rare case the `ipString` is not 8 characters long. This also requires for the method to have an `throws Exception` added, and you should probably choose a better exception rather than `Exception`.

Finally your write to file can be enhanced to the following:

```
//write IP Address to file
File file = new File("SomeFilePath.txt");
FileWriter fileWriter;

try {
    fileWriter = new FileWriter(file);
    fileWriter.write(
        String.format("ip=\"%s\"",
                      ipAddress.substring(0, ipAddress.length() - 1)));

    fileWriter.flush();
    fileWriter.close();

} catch (IOException exception) {
    exception.printStackTrace();
}
```

Finally some general notes on coding style:

- *Consider splitting into three functions* – These three code blocks could be extracted into (two or three) separate functions, where one serves as the output to the next. This would follow the single-responsibility principle of coding. One variant could change this function into:

  ```
  void WritePublicIPAddressToFile(String resp, String filename)
  {
     String ipAddress = findAndConvertIPAddress(resp);

     if (!ipAddress.isEmpty()) {
         writeIPAddressToFile(filename, ipAddress);
     }
  }
  ```

  Here I assume that the `findAndConvertIPAddress()` would return the empty string if the IP-address is not found as expected, and use that to bypass the file write if necessary. Now this function has a much clearer responsibility of finding and writing that IP-address to the file. No need to read lots of code to understand whats happening.
- *Use `StringBuilder` instead of `String` concatenation* – In general try to avoid building new strings to a minimum, and use `StringBuilder` when building new strings, or a variation over `String.format()`.
- *Consider having the filename as a parameter* – Your code might be constructed specific for Code Review, but with a name like `WritePublicIPAddressToFile` I would expect that `filename` was one of the parameters.
- *Avoid using `l` as variable name* – Especially in combination with `i` or `1`, it can be really confusing to use lower-case `L` as a variable name. Use more descriptive names instead.